Sufficient conditions for creating limits
Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" exercise 3.3.iv asks to

Prove that $F : C \to D$ creates limits for a particular class of diagrams if
both of the following hold:
(i) $C$ has those limits and $F$ preserves them.
(ii) $F : C \to D$ reflects isomorphisms.

The definition for "creating limits" in the book is a bit vague, so I'm using this elaboration.
The first part, $F$ reflecting limits, is fairly straightforward: if $\eta : c \Rightarrow K$, $K : J \to C$ being the diagram, is such that $F\eta$ is a limit [cone] in $D$, then, since $C$ has those limits, there's $\lambda : l \Rightarrow K$ a limit in $C$, so $F\lambda$ is a limit ($F$ is assumed to preserve limits) and $F c \cong F l$ (all limits are isomorphic), hence $c \cong l$ ($F$ reflects isos and there's an arrow $c \to l$ since $\lambda$ is a limit), hence $\eta$ is a limit.
Now, what about the actual limits creation? Suppose $\lambda^D : l^D \Rightarrow FK$ is a limit in $D$: that's the premise of the definition of "creating limits". Now, since $C$ has those limits again, $\exists \lambda^C : l^C \Rightarrow K$ a limit in $C$, and, since $F$ preserves limits, $F \lambda^C$ is a limit in $D$, which can trivially be lifted back to a limit in $C$. Hence $F$ creates limits.
This feels funny because I haven't actually used the premise of the existence of some $\lambda^D$, and the whole conclusion directly follows from one of the exercise premises (that $C$ has those limits), the hardest part of the exercise being proving reflection. Is it still a reasonable argument, or am I misunderstanding the whole definition of limits creation still?

Yes, your argument looks correct. The reason it seems weird is that being a limiting cone over $FK$ is the same as being isomorphic to $\lambda^D$ (as cones), because of the uniqueness of limits, so one natural way to phrase creation of limits (there is a limiting cone $\lambda^C$ over $K$ that $F$ maps to $\lambda^D$ up to isomorphism) can be rephrased to not mention $\lambda^D$ at all (there is a limiting cone $\lambda^C$ over $K$ that is preserved by $F$).
